# Merging arrays with passing a function as parameter

Tags: javascript, merge, callback

I've been on this problem for about 3 hours and I can't figure this out. I've gone through Codecademy and Code School Javascript courses, and according to the blog that hosted this code block, I should know the answer:

```
var merge = function(array1, array2, callback){  
  //your code here.
}

var x = merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], function(a, b){  
  return a + b;
});

//x should now equal [6, 8, 10, 12].
```

UPDATED WITH CORRECT CODE (Thank you so much T.J.!):

```
var merge = function(array1, array2, callback) {
  var i, newArray = [];

  for (i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = callback(array1[i], array2[i]);   
  }
  return newArray;
};

var x = merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], function(a, b){  
  return a + b;
});
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `merge`, you:

1. Create a new, blank array for the return value.
2. Consider what you want to do if `array1` and `array2` aren't the same length, although they are in the example usage.
3. Use an index variable to loop from `0` through `< array1.length` (most likely a `for` loop).
4. Fill in the entry for each index in your return value array by calling `callback`, passing the entry for that index from `array1` and from `array2` in as arguments and storing its return value in your array.
5. Return the new array.

Comment: @TJ Thank you! I was able to get the sum of the first index only (ill keep working on it), but I'm so confused as to what the callback parameter is doing when being called by function(a,b) in the new function? It seems like it creates additional parameters (a,b) that aren't being used?

Comment: @JoshZandman: See Evan's point -- I'd completely forgotten to tell you to use `callback`. I've updated #4 on the list to explain.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I finally figured this out! Thank you so much for not just posting the answer and instead giving me direction. I learned so much from this little exercise and it feels great.

Comment: @JoshZandman: Excellent stuff, Josh. Fantastic attitude as well. :-)

Comment: @JoshZandman: Re the solution you put in your question: One slight thing, you weren't declaring your `i` variable (I've fixed that for you). By not declaring it, you were falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Next thing to learn about: Strict mode. :-)